# how do i get ajax to use multiple checkbox values not only the first one?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a user management page and in it i have table like, first column of the table is checkboxes and the first one is a select all box. i want a button to take the value or values if the checkbox is ticked and send it in a post request. i wrote the code but it always and only sends the first value in the table no matter if any box is ticket or not.

the html table is like:

```
        <table id="userList" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Credential</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>               
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

the first column is check boxes that is filled from a php code with

`$userRows[] = '<input id="cbuserid" type="checkbox" name="check" value="'.$users['id'].'"/>';`

the check box select all script

```
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check');
    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<10;i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
```

i want to make a button to take the userid values and submit them in post request to disable multiple users at the same time the php code works fine but I'm not able to make the jquery part work:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.deactivateUsers', function(){
        var userid = $('#cbuserid').val();  
        var action = "userDeactivate";
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to deactivate this user?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{userid:userid, action:action},
                success:function(data) {                    
                    window.location.reload();
                    
                }
            })
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    });
```

this code always takes the first value of cbuserid no matter if any checkbox is ticked or not.

Comment: _"this code always takes the first value of cbuserid"_ - because you are violating the basic rule, that element IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Remove the ID, and use `$('.check:checked').val();` to get the values of all checked checkboxes of that class as an array.

Comment: i tried and it didn't work still only posts first value

Comment: @CBroe `.val()` always takes the value of the first element in the jquery collection: https://jsfiddle.net/m3frc8q5/.  If you want all values you'll need to use .map, eg: `$(".checkchecked").map((i,e)=>e.value).toArray()`

Comment: @freedomn-m right, I got it the wrong way round there for a second, _setting_ one value for multiple elements works that way.

Comment: @freedomn-m another problem now this var userid = $(".check:checked").map((i,e)=>e.value).toArray() shows the correct request being sent but when i open the console and inspect the response i can see that only the last value is being processed but if i resend the same request that was sent by ajax it works ...

Comment: Have you changed your action.php to handle an array?  What is the value in the php?  Is it an array?

Comment: @freedomn-m action.php calls a function in another file the function is 
``` public function deactivateUser(){
   $conn = $this->dbConnect;
   $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE user SET status = "deactivated",credential = "" WHERE id = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
   $userids = $_POST["userid"];
   $array = explode(",", $userids);
    foreach($array as $userid){
   $exec = $stmt->execute(); 
   echo "$userid <br>";
  } 
 } ```

oh yeah I'm using explode because in the ajax request i specified traditional: true, because php wasn't taking userid[] as a array for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the onclick property for the button and add

```
data-user="'.$users['id'].'"
```

Something like that::

```
<input type="button" onclick="function_name()" data-user="'.$users['id'].'">
function function_name()
{
  let id = $(this).attr("data-user");
}
```

or without data

```
<input type="button" onclick="function_name("'.$users['id'].'")">
function function_name(user_id)
{
  let id = user_id;
}
```

You can use the approach with data attributes

```
<input class="checkbox-user" type="checkbox" data-user="'.$users['id'].'"/>

$('input:checkbox:checkbox-user').each(function () {
    if(this.checked)
        console.log($(this).attr("data-user"););
});
```